# replace CR LF characters with CR (windows)

Tags: ruby, windows

I have a ruby script that parses a file and is supposed to replace all CR-LF characters with CR.

```
def fixNewline(filename)
  p "scrubbing final xml"
  newFilename = filename.split('.')[0]
  File.open("#{newFilename}.scrubbed.xml", 'w') do |fo|
    File.foreach(filename) do |li|
      fo.puts li.gsub(/\r\n/, "\r")
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately when I look at the file in notepad++ I still see \r\n sequences. I think that this is because puts is adding a \r\n to the end of the line. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`IO#print`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-print) instead of [`IO#puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-puts).